# Is there a relevance criterion for tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I recently voted to reject [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4402809) to give a description to the [`xkcd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xkcd) tag. The description provided was fine, but the tag just seems like it doesn't need to exist. There's [only one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317421/how-to-disable-mobile-redirect-on-a-website-i-dont-control) tagged with it, and even there, xkcd is only given as one example of a site — the question isn't about anything specific to xkcd's APIs, links etc. Seems like a better edit would have been to just remove the tag from the question.

I'm fine with being forward-thinking as far as tags that don't exist yet but should (after all, every tag starts out with only one question!), but I can't imagine there's a huge demand for asking about xkcd in a programming forum.

However, the edit was accepted, and I was the only person to vote to reject it. That indicates to me that I'm in the wrong. I'm not here to argue that I'm right, but rather to ask why I'm wrong. Does a tag need to have any relevance to programming? And if so, where is that line (and why does xkcd pass the test)?

The question that tagged xkcd also mentions dining halls — in fact, more than it mentions xkcd! Would we also accept a `dining hall` tag?

Comment: @MartijnPieters So is the correct thing to (1) accept the edit to the tag, since it's valid; (2) edit the question to remove the tag; (3) wait for the system to automatically remove the tag, since it's not used in any question?

Comment: A whole lot of plagiarism in that wiki as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XKCD link is only there to illustrate the story told. It's not an example, just a comic about the very issue under discussion. The tag is totally useless there and I removed it.

The reviewers didn't even pay attention to how useful the tag is; it isn't and you shouldn't be discouraged by the edit being accepted. The tag will be cleared from Stack Overflow come 03:00 UTC.

(The tag edit is irrelevant as the wiki will be deleted with the tag. Ignore the edit to the tag wiki, next time just remove the tag).